# How can I save a String Byte without losing information?

Tags: java, string, int, byte, bitset

I'm developing a JPEG decoder(I'm in the Huffman phase) and I want to **write BinaryString's into a file.** 
For example, let's say we've this:

```java
String huff = "00010010100010101000100100";
```

I've tried to convert it to an integer spliting it by 8 and saving it integer represantation, as I can't write bits:

```java
huff.split("(?<=\\G.{8})"))
int val = Integer.parseInt(str, 2);
out.write(val); //writes to a FileOutputStream
```

The problem is that, in my example, if I try to save **"00010010"** it converts it to **18** (10010), and **I need the 0's.**

And finally,  when I read :

```java
int enter;
String code = "";
    while((enter =in.read())!=-1) {
            code+=Integer.toBinaryString(enter);
        }
```

I got :

```java
Code = 10010
```

instead of:

```java
Code = 00010010
```

Also I've tried to convert it to bitset and then to Byte[] but I've the same problem.

Comment: This doesn't "lose" information, in the sense that you know the missing bits are all zero. What you need is just to left-pad the result with zeroes.

Comment: @kaya3 Ok, but when I try to read the file, how do I know that I got some zeros and  I need to left-pad the result?

Comment: You *always* need to left-pad the result. Left-pad means filling from the left to a particular length; your desired length is 8, so if the string's length is already 8, left-padding won't change it.

Comment: @kaya3 I've edited my question because I think that to left-pad isn't the solution :(

Comment: Implementing Huffman coding with strings like that is an absolute disaster for performance. Not just slow, but disaster-level slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is that you have the string `"10010"` and you want the string `"00010010"`. That is, you need to left-pad this string with zeroes. Note that since you're joining the results of many calls to `Integer.toBinaryString` in a loop, you need to left-pad these strings inside the loop, before concatenating them.

```
while((enter = in.read()) != -1) {
    String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(enter);
    // left-pad to length 8
    binary = ("00000000" + binary).substring(binary.length());
    code += binary;
}
```

Comment: Less work: `binary = "00000000".substring(binary.length()) + binary;`

Answer (score -2):

You might want to look at the UTF-8 algorithm, since it does exactly what you want. It stores massive amounts of data while discarding zeros, keeping relevant data, and encoding it to take up less disk space.

> Works with: Java version 7+

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class UTF8EncodeDecode {

    public static byte[] utf8encode(int codepoint) {
        return new String(new int[]{codepoint}, 0, 1).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    public static int utf8decode(byte[] bytes) {
        return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).codePointAt(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("%-7s %-43s %7s\t%s\t%7s%n",
                "Char", "Name", "Unicode", "UTF-8 encoded", "Decoded");

        for (int codepoint : new int[]{0x0041, 0x00F6, 0x0416, 0x20AC, 0x1D11E}) {
            byte[] encoded = utf8encode(codepoint);
            Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
            for (byte b : encoded) {
                formatter.format("%02X ", b);
            }
            String encodedHex = formatter.toString();
            int decoded = utf8decode(encoded);
            System.out.printf("%-7c %-43s U+%04X\t%-12s\tU+%04X%n",
                    codepoint, Character.getName(codepoint), codepoint, encodedHex, decoded);
        }
    }
}
```

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/UTF-8_encode_and_decode#Java

> UTF-8 is a variable width character encoding capable of encoding all 1,112,064[nb 1] valid code points in Unicode using one to four 8-bit bytes.[nb 2] The encoding is defined by the Unicode Standard, and was originally designed by Ken Thompson and Rob Pike.[1][2] The name is derived from Unicode (or Universal Coded Character Set) Transformation Format – 8-bit.[3]
>
> It was designed for backward compatibility with ASCII. Code points with lower numerical values, which tend to occur more frequently, are encoded using fewer bytes. The first 128 characters of Unicode, which correspond one-to-one with ASCII, are encoded using a single byte with the same binary value as ASCII, so that valid ASCII text is valid UTF-8-encoded Unicode as well. Since ASCII bytes do not occur when encoding non-ASCII code points into UTF-8, UTF-8 is safe to use within most programming and document languages that interpret certain ASCII characters in a special way, such as "/" (slash) in filenames, "\" (backslash) in escape sequences, and "%" in printf.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Binary `11110000 10010000 10001101 10001000` becomes `F0 90 8D 88` in UTF-8. Since you are storing it as text, you go from having to store 32 characters to storing 8. And because it's a well known and well designed encoding, you can reverse it easily. All the math is done for you.

Your example of `00010010100010101000100100` (or rather `00000001 0010100 0101010 00100100`) converts to `*$` (two unprintable characters on my machine). That's the UTF-8 encoding of the binary. I had mistakenly used a different site that was using the data I put in as decimal instead of binary.

https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-binary-to-utf8

For a really good explanation of UTF-8 and how it can apply to the answer:

https://hackaday.com/2013/09/27/utf-8-the-most-elegant-hack/

Edit:

I took this question as a way to reduce the amount of characters needed to store values, which is a type of encoding. UTF-8 is a type of encoding. Used in a "non-standard" way, the OP can use UTF-8 to encode their strings of 0's & 1's in a much shorter format. That's how this answer is relevant.

If you concatenate the characters, you can go from 4x 8 bits (32 bits) to 8x 8 bits (64 bits) easily and encode a value as large as 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. The string in the question contains only the characters `'0'` and `'1'`.

Comment: @kaya3, UTF-8 is a way to condense binary data into smaller byte chunks.

Comment: No, UTF-8 is a way to encode text data. Binary data can be encoded with 8 bits per byte in a trivial way, and of course you can't do better than that by imagining that the data represents text.

Comment: @kaya3, it's a way of encoding binary into hex values, so yes, it's a much better way of storing the data. Check out my new last paragraph.

Comment: Based on your last paragraph, I suspect you do not understand the difference between UTF-8 and hexadecimal.

Comment: @kaya3, based on your last comment, you don't understand the question. The OP wants to shrink the string they store. Turning a long string of 1' & 0's into characters that have the same binary representation as the original string is the exact way to reversibly compress the data. The OP's example is a 26 character string, so 26*4 bytes = 104 bytes of stored data. Encoded as 4x UTF-8 characters, it's only 16 bytes. It's much more efficient than what they are currently trying to do, which is develop their own compression algorithm.

Comment: Thanks @computercarguy, but I've the same problem. Because if you try to decode the `ϲeϨ✚` the result is : 01010001010100010010.  And I need 00010010100010101000100100.

Comment: No, that is not what the question is about at all. The question clearly states that they want a binary string as a string of 1s and 0s, including leading zeroes. The given example is that the string "00010010" is desired but the code currently produces the result "10010" instead. It has nothing to do with what you said; the OP mentions nothing about "shrinking" or compression.

Comment: Besides being far away from the question’s intent, which clearly refers to JPEG, a well defined format that can’t be replaced by an arbitrary choice for UTF-8, how can you call a method that only works for the range of 0 to 1,112,064 (you cited the number yourself) a viable method to encode an `int` which can have the range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647?

Comment: @Holger, I took this question as a way to reduce the amount of characters needed to store values, which is a type of encoding. UTF-8 is a type of encoding. Used in a "non-standard" way, the OP can use UTF-8 to encode his strings of 0's & 1's in a much shorter format. That's how my answer is relevant. Also, if you concatenate the characters, you can go from 4x8 bits to 8x8 bits easily and encode a value as large as 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. I guess I don't understand how people can't see this.